# How to integrate LeanFT Selenium with HP QC

Tags: selenium, hp-uft, hp-quality-center, hp-alm, leanft

Now I am using Selenium (Java + Maven + Jenkins + TestNG + GitHub) with Microsoft Test Manager (Test Management Tool) for UI Automation. Microsoft Test Manager provides the APIs to integrate/map the manual tests from test manager to automated tests from Selenium.

Now we are planning to use LeanFT with Selenium (with LeanFt we can use Selenium, .Net- Visual Studio or UFT) for UI automation and HP QC (Test Management Tool).

Here I want to know:

1. How to integrate LeanFT Selenium with HP QC or How to map manual tests from HP QC to automated tests in LeanFT Selenium? (If you are using QTP/UFT you can open the manual test in QC and click on QTP/UFT icon to create related automated test).
2. Which tool can be used for SCM or Version Control, git and GitHub or LeanFT provides in built support for java code also? (In case if you are using QTP, no need to use external SCM).
3. From where to run the tests, from Jenkins or QC (In QTP + QC integration, you can run tests directly from QC also)?

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer your questions:

1. Which version of HPE ALM(QC) you use? Is it already the new gig called ALM Octane? In case you have an older version you need to think about **VAPI-XP** Tests. **This is the generic test type for everything that HPE QC doesn't support out-of-the-box**. Newer versions of HPE ALM however support LeanFT as a Test Type. Here is the [offical doc](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.55/online_help/Content/UG/r_test_types.htm) on test types for the latest version and [here](http://eyeonquality.com/running-hpe-leanft-tests-from-hpe-alm-part-one/) a little tutorial.
2. Unlike UFT, LeanFT is just the Test Automation Framework, it does not come bundled with an IDE (Which I personally consider good) - so depending on the IDE you use to develop code (eclipse, intellij, visual studio) - you can and should use any plugin that supports it. Definitely git is an easy and good pick.
3. Jenkins has plugins to trigger UFT Tests from QC or the FileSystem and then pick-up results automatically. In the case of *LeanFT as mentioned it neither comes bundled with an IDE or Test Execution Engine* so you can use **JUnit, TestNG** or any other execution engine to achieve this. For doing full Continuous Integration; QC is not that good (HPE seemed to abandon development there) so it is definitely **Jenkins**. The new Gig(Octane) did not even try to build an own CI System but just wrapped Object models of [existing  ones](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/octane/en/latest/Online/Content/AdminGuide/article_CI_servers_setup.htm) into it's own pipeline representations. For integrating with QC, you may have to write some scripting / utilities to upload stuff to QC using the OTA API - which is the client side Automation Framework of HPE QC

Answer (score 0):

Below are the tutorials for OTA API if you need them

https://sumeetkushwah.com/2015/03/19/connecting-almqc-using-hps-otaopen-test-architecture-api/

And here is a github project with alot of examples and wrapper functions

https://github.com/sumeet-kushwah/ALM_OTA_Wrapper

Best place to run tests is from jenkins as suggested by Bela. Below is the article detailing that process

https://sumeetkushwah.com/2015/03/24/implementing-ci-using-jenkins-and-uft/